# Is it possible to add new layers to Caffe?

Tags: caffe, matcaffe

Is it possible for me to add a new layer (for a different loss) with Caffe?
How can I do it using Matlab or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a custom loss function with pycaffe. Here is an example of Euclidean loss layer in python (taken from [Caffe Github repo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py)). You need to provide the loss function in forward function and it's gradient in backward method:

```
import caffe
import numpy as np

class EuclideanLossLayer(caffe.Layer):
    """
    Compute the Euclidean Loss in the same manner as the C++ EuclideanLossLayer
    to demonstrate the class interface for developing layers in Python.
    """

    def setup(self, bottom, top):
        # check input pair
        if len(bottom) != 2:
            raise Exception("Need two inputs to compute distance.")

    def reshape(self, bottom, top):
        # check input dimensions match
        if bottom[0].count != bottom[1].count:
            raise Exception("Inputs must have the same dimension.")
        # difference is shape of inputs
        self.diff = np.zeros_like(bottom[0].data, dtype=np.float32)
        # loss output is scalar
        top[0].reshape(1)

    def forward(self, bottom, top):
        self.diff[...] = bottom[0].data - bottom[1].data
        top[0].data[...] = np.sum(self.diff**2) / bottom[0].num / 2.

    def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
        for i in range(2):
            if not propagate_down[i]:
                continue
            if i == 0:
                sign = 1
            else:
                sign = -1
            bottom[i].diff[...] = sign * self.diff / bottom[i].num
```

Save it as pyloss.py for example. You can then use the python layer in your prototxt file to load it:

```
layer {
  type: 'Python'
  name: 'loss'
  top: 'loss'
  bottom: 'ipx'
  bottom: 'ipy'
  python_param {
    # the module name -- usually the filename -- that needs to be in $PYTHONPATH
    module: 'pyloss'
    # the layer name -- the class name in the module
    layer: 'EuclideanLossLayer'
  }
  # set loss weight so Caffe knows this is a loss layer.
  # since PythonLayer inherits directly from Layer, this isn't automatically
  # known to Caffe
  loss_weight: 1
}
```

Or in your python script:

```
n.loss = L.Python(n.ipx, n.ipy,python_param=dict(module='pyloss',layer='EuclideanLossLayer'),
                     loss_weight=1)
```

Just be very careful in computing and implemeting the gradient (backward function) since it tends to be error-prone.

Comment: you can use [this implementation](https://github.com/tnarihi/caffe/blob/python-gradient-checker/python/caffe/test/test_gradient_checker.py) of gradient check util for python.